# "Unfortunately, application has stopped" for some version of Android

Tags: android, crash, launch

I have an application available on Google Play. Some people told me they were having an issue. When they open the application, it directly crashes and says "Unfortunately, [application name] has stopped".
When I started to program my project, I had the same problem with an Android 4.2.2. I just told me that it was a problem only for this version of Android, because when I used my bother's phone and my friends' phone everything worked. But finally not. People are having the same issue with and Android 5.0 or Android 5.0.2, and maybe some more.

I have few other red lines, but I will show you only the biggest part, which seems suspect. When I launch my app, I get this :

```
08-19 21:27:35.135 26504-26504/com.histoire_horreur E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.histoire_horreur.Listener.ScrollListener
                                                                      at com.histoire_horreur.MainActivity.createView(MainActivity.java:59)
                                                                      at com.histoire_horreur.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Android Studio doesn't underline any line in my code to tell me that this class is not found. ScrollListener is a class I created and it exists. I imported it. Anyway... I decided to delete line 59 to see what happens. When I did, I get a new error :

```
08-19 21:33:09.317 26953-26953/com.histoire_horreur E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.initializePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1232)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1296)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1591)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:91)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:130)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This error is a mystery for me. I didn't even use MenuBuilder somewhere.
Can you help me because I now don't know where to focus. I searched a lot on StackOverflow and nothing solved my problem. There are a lot of similar errors but with a different log. Some people who had the same issue said it was just a problem of Android 4.2.2. But it is not.

Comment: Do you get this error on `release` and `debug` version or only on your `release` version ?

Comment: I get this on my own phone (Android 4.2.2.) I open Android Studio and I launch project on my phone.
I guess for Android 5.0 it's the same error ?
I don't know how to get errors from release version. I tried to watch in the play store, and there is page for crashes and ANR but nothing is written.

Comment: I just remember a tip. Currently I have this :
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { ... }
When I started to develop, a friend told me that I should do something like this :
public class MainActivity extends Activity { ... }
And it worked. The only problem was that the toolbar disappeared, that's why I can't use this tip. But it worked for Android 4.2.2.
Maybe it can give you an idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About MenuBuilder problem, you need to change your build.gradle file as I did there :

[image]

Then it worked with my Wiko 4.2.2.

About ScrollListener problem, I will create a new subject.